# Categories or terms main page

Tags: wordpress

When you have a link like this

> yoursite.com/category/food/

is it possible in WordPress to make category link accessible:

> yoursite.com/category/

so it would show dynamically all the categories in this page, I want to achieve this with a custom taxonomy that I have, is there a template for this by WP?
Right now what I see it always returns 404, which is not nice.

I know I can achieve this by creating a custom page template and adding queries but what I want to know is if I can do it the right way on the same link as /category

Comment: So, if someone visits /category what should you see?

Comment: @Rob list of all available categories, as an example.